# Dataset throwing System.Data.ConstraintException

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a legacy desktop app written in VB.NET that reads from a SQL Server DB using stored procedures and populates a DataTable inside a DataSet.
It is always throwing **Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.**
Doing several recommended steps, I found that the stored procedure is returning *NULL* for date columns called *Valid From* and *Valid To*.

In the create table it shows this

```
Create Table REC (…
    ValidFrom datetime NULL,
    ValidTo datetime NULL,
…);
```

In the `DataSet` property, I have **AllowDBNull** set to true and **DefaultValue** set to `DBNull`.

Using the immediate window, I do `?dataset1.HRS_GetCME.geterrors(0)`, I get `RowError: "Column 'Valid To' does not allow DBNull.Value."` and `Valid_To: 'DirectCast(dataset1.HRS_GetCME.geterrors(0), COS.DataSet1.HRS_GetCMERow).Valid_To' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'`

**EDIT:** As requested by Marc Gravell.

```vbnet
Private Sub InitAdapter()
    Me._adapter = New Global.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim tableMapping As Global.System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping =
        New Global.System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping()

    tableMapping.SourceTable = "Table"
    tableMapping.DataSetTable = "HRS_GetCME"
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID")
    // ...
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Date Taken", "Date Taken")
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Valid From", "Valid From")
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Valid To", "Valid To")
    // ...
    Me._adapter.TableMappings.Add(tableMapping)
End Sub
```

I do not have a DirectCast in all my code, where is it from and how to solve it?

Comment: The issue is the `DataTable`, not the database. The error message is telling you that the `DataTable` doesn't allow nulls in that column so look at the configuration of that column in the `DataTable` and fix that if it's not what you want.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I am allowing DBNulls, I wrote it in the question.

Comment: @Joe can you show us that in code? Your note in the question talks about the DataSet property: but this isn't a DataSet thing - it is a DataTable/DataColumn thing. Code speaks loudest. Please show us the code where you're initializing those columns.

Comment: On a side note: DataSet/DataTable haven't been the best choice for data access in a very very long time (they were basically a migration technology for ADO recordsets in the VB6 era). It is much much easier to work with POCOs and either EF or Dapper (or another other similar tool). If you choose to use them, fine, but ...

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree but it is not really my choice, you've got to see how it creates its menus, it populates them in some weird way from the database too.

Comment: Your first snippet indicates that the database column is named `ValidFrom` but your second snippet indicates that you're trying to map from a column named `Valid From`. That doesn't seem right. Also, there's nothing in your edit to back up your claim that that column allows nulls.

Comment: I set the AllowDBNull to true in the field property in the xsd properties window.

Comment: I don't see anything that would tie your xsd properties window to anything relevant here... in C# terms, I'm expecting to see something like: `DataTable table = new DataTable(); table.Columns.Add("ValidFrom", typeof(DateTime)).AllowDBNull = true;`

Comment: You are correct, please post your answer in order to upvote it. The problem is that when I change the `AllowDBNull` in the xsd it does not reflect in the dataset1.Designer.vb. It stayed false. I am modifying it manually.